# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.16.0): Connection GRPC stream error. Code: 1 Message: 1 CANCELLED: The operation was cancelled

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following webhook, and it is listening for a payment provider API to update the status of an order once it is 'paid'. In logs for Firebase Functions, I get the console log `Payment status paid` meaning that I get the update of the order correctly. However, when I try to call the function responsible for updating Firestore, I get the following:

`@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.16.0): Connection GRPC stream error. Code: 13 Message: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2`

```
exports.webhooks = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {
  mollieClient.payments
    .get(req.body.id)
    .then((payment) => {
      console.log("Payment status " + payment.status);

      if (payment.isPaid()) {
        updateOrderStatusPaid(req.body.id);
        return null;
      }
      return null;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.send(error);
    });
  console.log("Request body " + req.body);
});

function updateOrderStatusPaid(orderId) {
  firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("orders")
  .where("paymentId", "==", orderId)
  .update({
    status: payment.status
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log("Success");
    return null;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error " + error);
  });
}
```

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mollie/api-client": "^3.2.4",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.16.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "grpc": "^1.24.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I cannot find anything specific to this problem. I am already using Firestore on my server side so there is no problem with initialization of Firebase. Maybe somebody knows where the problem might be or suggest something I should do to solve this. Thank you!

The closest link to this problem is https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/679 where still there is not answer.

Comment: This issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1023) I believe and the investigation is still ongoing. Updating `@grpc/grpc-js` might mitigate it partially.

Comment: @EmilGi Thanks, I see in my ```package-lock.json``` file that my ```@grpc/grpc-js``` has version ```"1.0.5"```, meanwhile in npmjs.com the latest version is ```1.24.4```. I have used command ```npm i --package-lock-only``` to update my ```package-lock.json``` file but I see that version has not changed. Could you please tell me how to update it correctly?

Comment: You can specify it in your `package.json` as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies).

Comment: @EmilGi, I have included ```grpc: "^1.24.4"``` to my dependencies in ```package.json``` file by running ```npm i grpc```, as I understood from that reference from Firebase. I still get the same error, I believe that this did not change anything and I am sure that I did not do what I think I should have done to solve this issue. Could you please explain in few words how to do it exactly? ....

Comment: Could you please share your package.json file? And please note even you set the correct grpc version, the issue in some cases still persists as the GitHub thread is still opened and some users are still facing it.

Comment: @NibrassH Thank you for your message. I updated my question and provided the file.

Comment: I can see that you have indeed added the correct grpc version. However you are still getting the errors. So this means still the issue persists, in this case please keep track of the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1023) and also post their your issue.